# How to numerically integrate the time of two oscillatory functions from NDEigensystem

Tags: numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I am trying to numerically integrate phi*psi. And no matter which method I chose, the NIntegrate failed.

```
L = 1000*10^-10;
F = 10^7;
m = 0.0665*9.1*10^-31;
mhole = 0.34*9.1*10^-31;
e = 1.6*10^-19;
 \[HBar] = 1.05*10^-34; 
Ne = 199;

eqn1 = (-(\[HBar]^2/(2 m))*(\[Phi]'')[x] + e*F*x*\[Phi][x]);
eqn2 = (-(\[HBar]^2/(2 mhole))*(\[Psi]'')[x] - e*F*x*\[Psi][x])
{phivals, phifuns} = 
  NDEigensystem[{eqn1, 
    DirichletCondition[\[Phi][x] == 0, 
     x >= L/2 || x <= -L/2]}, \[Phi][x], {x, -L/2, 
    L/2}, Ne, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
{"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-9}}}}];
{psivals, psifuns} = 
  NDEigensystem[{eqn2, 
    DirichletCondition[\[Psi][x] == 0, 
     x >= L/2 || x <= -L/2]}, \[Psi][x], {x, -L/2, 
    L/2}, Ne, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-9}}}}];


 Itable = Table[Abs[NIntegrate[psifuns[[i]]*phifuns[[j]], {x, -L/2, L/2},  Method -> {"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"}]], {i, Ne}, {j, Ne}];
```

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Please add the code to the question it self and not in a comment. You can edit your question to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this better:

```
mesh = psifuns[[1]][[0]]["ElementMesh"];
NIntegrate[psifuns[[1]]*phifuns[[1]], {x} \[Element] mesh]
-0.19244714343860325`
```

And then

```
Table[NIntegrate[psifuns[[i]]*phifuns[[j]], {x} \[Element] mesh], {i, 
  Ne}, {j, Ne}]
```

Comment: but I need psifun[[i]]*phifuns[[j]] for all i and j

Comment: @Sha-Han Yes, put it back in the loop. This was just a simplified example.

Comment: Can you write a complete version. I don't know how to define mesh in the complete version

Comment: @Sha-Han, see updated answer. Unfortunately, I made a mistake editing your question and forgot to add the `Table` command. Sorry about that. Could you re-add that please.

Comment: @Sha-Han, fixed the edit mistake.